# Repeated Eigenvector/Eigenvalue matrix method

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

So I am having trouble with finding the generalized solution and I am not sure why my answer is interpreted as incorrect and I wanted to double check.

$$ \overrightarrow{y'} = \begin{pmatrix} -6 & 1 \\ 0 & -6  \end{pmatrix} \overrightarrow{y} $$

I found the eigenvalue of $$ \lambda = -6 $$

Then I found the eigenvectors of

$$ \overrightarrow{v_1 } = \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0  \end{pmatrix}  $$
$$ \overrightarrow{v_2 } = \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1  \end{pmatrix}  $$

Then to find the generalized solution, I used

$$ \overrightarrow{y}(t) = (c_1 )\begin{pmatrix} e^{-6t} \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} + (c_2)\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ e^{-6t} \end{pmatrix}$$

However, my general solution here is interpreted as being incorrect. I also tried different eigenvectors and is still incorrect. I am really stuck as to where Im making an error

Comment: $v_1$ surely is an eigenvector. But is $v_2$ an eigenvector? What would happen if we didn't have $1$ but $0$ in the upper right corner?

Comment: Ah I managed to find the answer. But a follow up question would be how do we know which eigenvector corresponds to c1 and c2 in the general solution ? Why couldn't it be the case that I write $$ \overrightarrow{y}(t) = (c_1 )\begin{pmatrix} e^{-6t} \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} + (c_2)(\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}te^{-6t} + \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}e^{-6t}) $$

Comment: instead of $$ \overrightarrow{y}(t) = (c_2 )\begin{pmatrix} e^{-6t} \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} + (c_1)(\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}te^{-6t} + \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}e^{-6t}) $$ Is it due to the position in the original matrix ? Thanks

Comment: Ah I believe its clear now, thanks !